# Combine two tables in MySQL for a newbie

Tags: mysql

I want to combine two tables.

**Table 1**

```
+----+--------+
| id |  fund  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | a fund |
|  2 | b fund |
|  3 | c fund |
+----+--------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+--------+-----------+
|   id   | projects  |
+--------+-----------+
| 100001 | a project |
| 100002 | b project |
| 100003 | c project |
+--------+-----------+
```

I want both of these tables combined together to make

**Table 3**

```
+--------+-----------+
|   id   | projects  |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | a fund    |
|      2 | b fund    |
|      3 | c fund    |
| 100001 | a project |
| 100002 | b project |
| 100003 | c project |
+--------+-----------+
```

This is not to merge permanently, but to display in a select box.

Comment: For future reference you can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to make formatted tables, although I admire the amount of effort you put into these.

Comment: Also you just want a `union all` with an alias

Comment: what have you tried before asking so?

Comment: or a `union` if you want to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Note however when using a union or union all, the number of columns in each query must match AND the data types must be the same or be able to be implicitly cast to the type of the 1st table's data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL for this:

```
select id, fund projects 
from table1
union all
select id, projects
from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `fund` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `fund`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a fund'),
    (2, 'b fund'),
    (3, 'c fund')
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`id` int, `projects` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`id`, `projects`)
VALUES
    (100001, 'a project'),
    (100002, 'b project'),
    (100003, 'c project')
select * from table1 
union 
select * from table2
```